# Dynamic template in angular with qtip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qtip2

To display some user information I am using a directive that captures the click event to display a [qTip](http://qtip2.com/) tooltip. As I am already using angular, to render the HTML I am using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to render the HTML.

```
.directive('myDirective', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Open qTip popup
            element.qtip({
                content: {
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/myurl',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            // Contact full name
                            scope.FullName = data.contact.Forename + ' ' + data.contact.Surname;

                            var myelement = angular.element('<p>[[ FullName ]]</p>');
                            var compiled = $compile(myelement)(scope);

                            this.set('content.text', compiled)
                        }
                    }
                },
                show: 'click',
                style: {
                    classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'unfocus'
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that the HTML is only rendered some times while in other cases I can see the angular tags coming. It seemed that compiler output was not rendered at time. To solved, I found a solution using a timeout like it shows in the code below.

```
...
success: function (data, status) {
  // Contact full name
  scope.FullName = data.contact.Forename + ' ' + data.contact.Surname;

  var myelement = angular.element('<p>[[ FullName ]]</p>');
  var compiled = $compile(myelement)(scope);

  $timeout(this.set('content.text', compiled), 100); // delay 100 ms
}
...
```

My problem is that I do not find this solution very efficient and I would like to know if there is a better alternative to this approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout(this.set('content.text', compiled), 100);`

Your timeout function is wrong, as it will execute immediately. But it works because the missing part is to start an angular `digest` process to update the GUI, because qTip is running outside the angular lifecycle. `$timeout` will implicitly call the `digest` function.

Try this:

```
this.set('content.text', compiled)l
scope.$digest();
```

Correct implementation of your timeout function:

```
var that = this;
$timeout(function() {
    that.set('content.text', compiled);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me, many thanks for the explanation. I actually spent some time trying to work out why $compile did not work, now it makes sense.